# What role does Java play in Cyber Security

Tags: penetration-test, java

I'm interested in the world of Cyber Security and the role that Java development plays within it. Is Java used as a language for carrying out pen testing for instance? If anyone has any pointers or useful links to how Java is used within Cyber Security, then could they please post them in reply?

Comment: Any programming language can be used for any task. It's more of a question of whether the language meets the needs of the goal.

Comment: For about a decade Java 'sandbox' played the role of much-of-the-time highly-dangerous vector requiring thousands of websites to continuously issue advisories on blocking disabling and removing Java; now that applets have been exterminated, it plays the role of causing palpitations in people who experienced the last decade and bloating checklists of stale threats to waste resources on. </snark> in case that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is used occasionally for the development of penetration testing tools, such as Burp proxy, but generally Python is more preferred in the security community.

What is particularly interesting about Java from a security perspective are vulnerabilities that are particular to Java, such as deserialization and remote method invocation vulnerabilities. Of course, other languages have those vulnerabilities as well, but they seem to be more important for Java.

https://github.com/GrrrDog/Java-Deserialization-Cheat-Sheet